# Download list of images in S3 with boto3 and python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have two lists of urls and file name and I'd like to download it in my S3 bucket. But how to do it with lists ?
My url list:

```
gm_new = ['https://img.com/30.jpg', 'https://img.com/3.jpg']
```

My name file list:

```
ccv_name = ['30.jpg', '3.jpg']
```

My function:

```
def dl_imgs():
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    if gm_new is not None:
        req_img = requests.get(gm_new, stream=True)
        file_obj = req_img.raw
        req_data = file_obj.read()
        ccv_name_path = "images/" + ccv_name + ""
        #upload to S3
        s3.Bucket(_BUCKET_NAME_IMG).put_object(
            Key=ccv_name_path, Body=req_data, ContentType="image/jpeg", ACL="public-read")
dl_imgs()
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the urls list and file names and process item by item:

```
for url, file_name in zip(gm_new, ccv_name):
    <download file>
    <upload to s3>
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem now is that urls and file names are not in the good order, the `30.jpg` url can have the `3.jpg` name. Is there a solution there or do I have to create another solution before this part of code ?

Comment: in your example, urls and file lists are in order. `zip` will iterate over given lists and produce tuples: `('https://img.com/30.jpg', '30.jpg')`, `('https://img.com/3.jpg', '3.jpg')`.